# Swift DateFormatter from String with (EEST)?

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

i am trying to parse string date which is coming from an API to Date().

the date string is: `31-07-2023 12:44 (EEST)`

My code:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm (zzzz)" // "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"

if let ptdate = formatter.date(from: prayer.getString("time")) {
    // Not working!
}
```

i believe there is something missing in date format i am using which is `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm zzzz`, i am not sure what it is, since i've spent hours googling date formats.

Comment: The real problem is that that's sort of a crap string. Can you get them to do a better job at the server end?

Comment: @matt nope , i am using and open API for prayers timing , i agreed the date format is weird but is it possible to format it ?

Comment: What is "EEST"? That doesn't look like any time zone name I've ever seen. You need to figure out what that part of the string is and how to parse it. The rest of it seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: If you can get a list of the server's non-standard time zone names you might have to first do a substitution to standard time zone names and then use a StringFormatter.

Comment: maybe because you are not setting locale and timezone @Kodr.F

Comment: Actually, it looks like "EEST" is UTC +3. So you might be able to create a DateFormat string that handles date strings in that format directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this (no date formatter needed):

```
let dateString = "31-07-2023 12:44 (EEST)"
let format: Date.FormatString = "\(day: .twoDigits)-\(month: .twoDigits)-\(year: .defaultDigits) \(hour: .twoDigits(clock: .twentyFourHour, hourCycle: .oneBased)):\(minute: .twoDigits) (\(timeZone: .specificName(.short)))"
var strategy = Date.ParseStrategy.fixed(format: format, timeZone: .current)
let date = try? Date(dateString, strategy: strategy)
```

Comment: Its worked , 1 question , if EEST changed from the API to something else like another TZ this code will still work right ?

Comment: Nice fix from Matt Le Fleur, thanks

Comment: @Kodr.F I have no idea but I think we need to assume that it wouldn't change except maybe to EET which would still work (as you can confirm for yourself).

Comment: this is great , but if possible to make (EEST) optional ? as i've seen the API sometimes return the DT without timezone like only `31-07-2023 12:44`

Comment: That would be an even crappier date string than the one you have now. A date string without time zone information is utterly meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

For the `dateFormat` string you need to:

- Escape all string content with '
- Use 24h time format
- Use time zone specific non-location field code "z" (equivalents are: zz, zzz, zzzz)

```
let dateString = "31-07-2023 12:44 (EEST)"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm' ('z')"

if let ptdate: Date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
    print(ptdate)
}
```

Comment: I've tried the escaping `"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm ('zzzz')"` is still not working

Comment: It worked with the string you supplied ;-) I updated to 24h time format "dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm' ('z')", now it works for all values.

Answer (score 1):

"EEST" is a standard time zone abbreviation so you should use `zzz` and I also assume that the time format is 24h so configure the date formatter like this

```
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm (zzz)"
```

*Update*

Seems like a single `z` also works `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm (z)"`

Comment: i am not sure but i've removed (EEST) from the string before i parse it with the date formatter , dose this will effect the parse time ? is it safe to remove last string content after minutes and parse the time ?

Comment: If you remove the time zone then you will not get the correct time